# How to upgrade only one or two debian package

Tags: debian, upgrade

How to be able to upgrade only one or two Debian package, attempt

```
$ sudo apt  upgrade mpv
```

not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--only-upgrade` parameter with the package name or package list.

Example:

```
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade mpv
```

or

```
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade mpv wget curl
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apt install`. This is documented on the [apt-get manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt-get.8.en.html):

> This is also the target to use if you want to upgrade one or more already-installed packages without upgrading every package you have on your system.